# Minecraft PE connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When me and my friend on our phones try to play minecraft PE it doesn't show the name to go to the world, so we need answers on how this will work

Comment: Needs clarification of exactly what is happening before this can be reliably answered. Where doesn't it show a name? and the name of what?

Answer (score -1):

Check that LAN is on or off go to setting see if not. Then you version of MCPE it should be same as your friend if not. Then you wi-fi connection

Comment: We wi-fi connection... what? What should we do?